# How to set default parameter as 7 days ago to different date format on ssrs

Tags: date, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, default-value

I have default parameter and this parameter shows me 7 days ago with the expression below:

```
=DateAdd("d",-7,CDate(Format(Today(), "MM/dd/yyyy")))
```

But my report just running without error while the customer using "MM/dd/yyyy" time format.

Is there a way to use this parameter ALSO with "dd/MM/yyyy" format?

I would like to set a parameter to show 7 days ago but ı would like to use this parameter with both time format.

Thanks

Comment: if you want to  use another format, then add the days and then apply your format =Format(DateAdd("d",-7,CDate(Today())), "MM/dd/yyyy")

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the Format. Just put `=DateAdd("d",-7,Today())`. It will automatically take the Format according to System's format.

Answer (score 1):

A date is a value and values do not have a format. A date is *displayed* and has to be *entered* in a format that depends on the language settings of your browser. Using a date picker, you even don't have to care about the input format. So, just use an expression that calculates the desired value:

```
=Today.AddDays(-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the format part of your expression is redundant and misleading - don't use it

```
=DateAdd("d",-7,Today())
```

Secondly, you don't have any choice of how SSRS displays it's datepickers. It shows american format only (M/d/Y)